# Python: Sorting a nested dict by date

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have a large dict, but similar in concept to this:

```
data = {'business1': {'1/2':20, '1/4':10, '1/3':30}, 'business2': {'1/2':10, '1/4':20, '1/3':30}}
```

I want to sort the nested dicts by date. I understand how to do this when no nesting is involved, as shown below. I created a list, and I append the key, value pairs to the list and then sort.

```
data = {'1/2':20, '1/4':10, '1/3':30}

sorted_data = []
for key,value in data.iteritems():
    temp = (key,value)
    sorted_data.append(temp)
sorted_data.sort(key = lambda item: item[0], reverse=False)
print sorted_data
```

The problem is how to do this when dicts in dicts are involved, such as what I first mentioned:

```
data = {'business1': {'1/2':20, '1/4':10, '1/3':30}, 'business2': {'1/2':10, '1/4':20, '1/3':30}}
```

Comment: Any particular language you're planning to do this in?

Comment: A dict is unordered. Why are you looking to sort it? You might be looking for a list instead

Comment: Sorting a dict seems a little strange. Do you mean you want to present the contents of the dict in date order? (so, maybe a chart reflecting that for business1, January 2 was a 20 and January 3 was a 30 and so forth?) For this, I would suggest you do any sorting when you're rendering your data, and just sort on the keys kind of the way you're doing it now. (only, I'd probably get the keys, sort them, and then get the corresponding values, rather than constructing tuples... but horses for courses)

Comment: @inspectorG4dget Yes, I just updated the problem but that is essentially what I did in the example. The problem is going from a simple dict to nested dicts and doing the same for each nested dict.

Comment: @JonKiparsky Yes, the businesses don't need to be in order, but the nested dicts need to be in ascending order by date.

Comment: @alldayiwonder - Basically, nest a loop inside your loop. See my answer below. (Though as you'll see in my answer, your `for key,value in data.iteritems()` loop is actually unnecessary).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't said what you want your results to look like, but I would assume you want them to look like this:

```
result = {'business1': [('1/2',20), ('1/3',30), ('1/4',10)],
          'business2': [('1/2',10), ('1/3',30), ('1/4',20)]}
```

Here's how I would do it:

```
result = {}
for business_name, business_data in data.iteritems():
    # The following is basically your single-data loop
    sorted_data = []
    for key,value in business_data.iteritems():
        temp = (key,value)
        sorted_data.append(temp)
    sorted_data.sort(key = lambda item: item[0], reverse=False)
    result[business_name] = sorted_data
```

Now, you could save a step. The `for key,value in business_data.iteritems():` loop is basically repeating what `dict.items()` does. So you could replace four lines with `sorted_data = list(business_data.items())`. (The `list()` call is unnecessary in Python 2 but doesn't hurt anything, and it's needed in Python 3. Since you didn't say which version you're using, I left it in so that my answer will work on either Python 2 or Python 3).

So the final version I would suggest is:

```
result = {}
for business_name, business_data in data.iteritems():
    sorted_data = list(business_data.items())
    sorted_data.sort(key = lambda item: item[0], reverse=False)
    result[business_name] = sorted_data
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: By the way, be aware that if your dates look like your example code (i.e., strings with single digits for days or months before 10), sorting will put '1/10' before '1/2'. You'll want to convert your dates to a format like `"yyyy-mm-dd"`, with a fixed number of digits (and the year-month-day order) if you want string comparison to compare dates properly.

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import OrderedDict

for k,v in data.items():
    data[k] = OrderedDict(sorted(v.items()))

print data
```

user input:

```
 data = {'business1': {'1/2':20, '1/4':10, '1/3':30}, 'business2': {'1/2':10, '1/4':20, '1/3':30}}
```

output:

```
 {'business2': OrderedDict([('1/2', 10), ('1/3', 30), ('1/4', 20)]), 'business1': OrderedDict([('1/2', 20), ('1/3', 30), ('1/4', 10)])}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> data = {'business1': {'1/2':20, '1/4':10, '1/3':30}, 'business2': {'1/2':10, '1/4':20, '1/3':30}}
>>> {i:sorted(data[i].items(), key=lambda x: x[0]) for i in data}
{'business2': [('1/2', 10), ('1/3', 30), ('1/4', 20)], 'business1': [('1/2', 20), ('1/3', 30), ('1/4', 10)]}
```